# Nested arrow function gets global scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
class Service {
    static _runRequest = (request, success, failure) => {
        request.then(
            (response) => {
                if (ResponseHelper.wasSuccessful(response)) {
                    success(response);
                }
                else if (ResponseHelper.wasUnauthorized(response)) {
                    SessionHelper.refreshCurrentSession().then(
                        (refreshResponse) => {
                            if (refreshResponse === true) {
                                this._runRequest(request, success, failure);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

The issue is that, when calling `_runRequest` again if the session was refreshed successfully, `this` is pointing to the global scope.

Any ideas why and how to fix this? Shouldn't `this` stay the same no matter how many nested functions there are?

Comment: Please provide a working snippet that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: If you want it to point at `Service` then don't use an arrow as the `_runRequest`, use a normal function.

Comment: @loganfsmyth yup that solved it! wow yeah, as they say, arrow function isn't a silver bullet. Please create a proper answer so I can accept it.

Comment: The odd thing about this question is that you don't say what you expect the value of `this` to be or what it orginally was when `_runRequest()` first started to execute.  That probably would have immediately shown you where the problem was.  A little debugging can help you solve your own problems and/or allow you to ask a lot clearer questions.

Comment: @jfriend00 I thought it was obvious that I expected `this` to be the `Service` class, on which I'd be able to call `_runRequest` again.

Comment: Nope, that wasn't obvious to me.  I though you meant that `this` was wrong inside the second invocation of `_runRequest()`.  You didn't say you got an error on the `this._runRequest()` line because `this` does not point to `Service` like you expect.  Plus, anytime you have a lot of nested arrow functions and your `this` value isn't what you expect, you should back up the callchain and check it in the debugger or with `console.log()` statements and you quickly would have found where this issue is.  I'm trying to help you see how to solve your own problems rather than needing to come here.

Comment: @jfriend00 I see your point now, sorry about that. I just recently started developing with JS and probably skipped some context that was important for the question. You're right, I'll try and debug better now that I more aware of how the JS scoping works. Thank you for the help!

Comment: One thing to remember is to pretty much never define methods using arrow syntax because that defeats the expected assignment of `this` when the method executes.  Arrow syntax is a nice shorthand, but it is only for certain circumstances.  In this case, the non-arrow syntax is even shorter because it's a method definition which doesn't need the function keyword.

Comment: Worth noting that what you have is not ES6. Public class fields are a *proposal* (i.e. an experimental feature).

Answer (score 0):

In your code `this` will be the global object or `undefined` (depending on strict settings & environment), independent of the nesting level you are in. It is like that as soon as you execute the first line in the static method.

Instead of defining the static method with the arrow syntax, use the more established, short-cut function notation:

```
static _runRequest(request, success, failure) { // ...etc
```

This will make `this` refer to the "class" object.

See below for a comparison of the two ways of defining the static method, with simplified code (no nesting, no promises) using Babel:

```js
class Service1 {
    static _runRequest = (i) => {
        if (i == 0) {
          console.log('zero');
          return;
        }
        if (this && '_runRequest' in this) {
           return this._runRequest(0); // recurse
        }
        console.log('this is ' + this);
    }
}

Service1._runRequest(1);

class Service2 {
    static _runRequest(i) {
        if (i == 0) {
          console.log('zero');
          return;
        }
        if (this && '_runRequest' in this) {
           return this._runRequest(0); // recurse
        }
        console.log('this is ' + this);
    }
}

Service2._runRequest(1);
```